Is it possible to replace \" to \\" in apex?
I have a JSON object like the following:
{ "Test" : "Test \"hello\" world ", "Test2" : { "Test3": "Test \" ABC \" "}}

I want to replace all \" with \\". I tried to do this with regex but didn't have any luck.

Should be possible (just need to escape enough times). What have you tried? What was the result?

System.debug(test.replace('\\"', '\\\\"')); but it gives me:
USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|{ "Test" : "Test "hello" world ", "Test2" : { "Test3": "Test " ABC " "}}

Probably an XY problem. Where that json come from? What's the issue you're trying to solve? Have you taken into account typed deserialization?

Why do you need to do this? What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

I want to deserialize JSON to class and there is a problem

@RubenDG - JSON comes from callout to webservice. Typed or UnTyped deserialization do not work without double \

Usually you see \" when you try to print a valid json holding double quote via System.debug(), but it doesn't mean there are \" inside that string. I.E.: Map<String, Object> data = new Map<String, Object>{ 'Test' => 'Test "hello" world '}; data.put('Test2', new Map<String, Object>{ 'Test3' => 'Test " ABC " ' }); String jsonString = JSON.serialize(data); System.debug(jsonString); System.debug(JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString)); Here you'll see the escaped double quote in the first debug, yet the untyped deserialization works

@RubenDG - I know, but following fails: System.debug(JSON.deserializeUntyped('{ "Test" : "Test \"hello\" world ", "Test2" : { "Test3": "Test \" ABC \" "}}')); with: System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('h' (code 104)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries at [line:1, column:20]

That's because you are running this with a literal string, not a string received from an external system. The literal string, because you are in Apex, requires a double backslash.

Since the json comes from a webservice, you could use Postman, curl or any other tool to get it and to confirm it holds escaped double quote. If not, please edit the question posting the real json, how you tried to deserialize it and the error you got.

@RubenDG - main problem is that I downloading JSON file via GET request and that file have single backslashes " inside values.

@GrzegorzPołuch that is fine - Apex will deserialize that without issues as long as you receive the JSON via callout response or load the JSON from a file, e.g. by uploading the file as a static resource then using that as the source of the JSON for parsing. The only problem case you have is when you try to copy/paste it into (anon) apex.

It works as You said
